# Django forms. Make ChoiceField required on frontend <select>

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a Django form, which uses a ChoiceField:

```
control_model = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
```

(The reason 'choices' are empty is because they are set using a function based on my backend database)

The following is the entire form:

```
class CreateWorkflowForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(CreateWorkflowForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
      self.fields['control_model'].choices = my_function()
 
   control_model = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
   class Meta:
      model = CreateWorkflowModel
      fields = ['control_model']
```

The model used looks the following:

```
class CreateWorkflowModel(models.Model):
   control_model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I use this form in a Django template the following way:

```
<div class="form-content">
  {{ form.media }}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" id="id_submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

However on my webpage the `<select>` that corresponds to my ChoiceField doesn't have the attribute 'required':

[image: Image of HTML-Select]

This means that my form will fail if no value is input into the ChoiceField (because its required in the form) However I would much prefer if a popup box appeared on frontend stating "You need to enter a value on this field".

I know having the "required" value on the `<select>` would do this exact thing, however I don't know how to make django generate the `<select>` with this attribute.

Comment: Try to add first choice with empty value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need required attribute on your select, you must have first chose element with empty value, otherwise it's invalid HTML.
See [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/90ba716bf060ee7fef79dc230b0b20644839069f/django/forms/widgets.py#L692-L703) of the widget